# Unit test passes when running the test from within Visual Studio IDE but fails when using vstest.console.exe and Microsoft Fakes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, vstest

I have a solution, which contains numerous projects. Each of these projects has an associated test project which uses MSTest V2. Some of these test projects take advantage of Microsoft Fakes.

When I run the tests in the Visual Studio IDE, everything works fine. However, my build pipeline fails. I attempted to emulate what my build pipeline is doing and it also fails on my machine.

The error message I get is the following:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Fakes.ShimDateTime' from assembly 'mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ae41878053f6703'.

---

After playing around with the vstest.console.exe application, it seems that if I run each test assembly separately all of the tests pass, but if I attempt to pass in multiple assemblies which utilize Microsoft Fakes they fail.

- `vstest.console.exe "Path/To/First.dll"` Passes
- `vstest.console.exe "Path/To/Second.dll"` Passes
- `vstest.console.exe "Path/To/First.dll" "Path/To/Second.dll"` Fails
- `vstest.console.exe "Path/To/First.dll" "Path/To/Second.dll" /InIsolation` Fails

I'm not sure what is going on here or how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I've checked the vstest.console.exe [cli options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019) and there is no path for the test assembly names. Are both of test assembly using the MS.Fakes? please try to copy both test assemblies first.dll and second.dll to the same folder and run `vstest.console.exe first.dll second.dll`. I suppose that only one assembly uses the MS Fakes but vstest.console.exe can't find the mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes in `path/to`.

Comment: this is not a programming issue and cannot be easily replicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out what the problem was:

**Test Project A** had not defined `System.DateTime` in a Microsoft Fakes config file, so an assembly was generated named `mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll` which was missing the `System.Fakes.ShimDateTime`.

**Test Project B** had defined `System.DateTime` in a Microsoft Fakes config file, so an assembly was generated named `mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll` which contained the type `System.Fakes.ShimDateTime`.

This lead the following structure:

- ProjectA.Tests/bin/Debug/

  - `ProjectA.Tests.dll` -- Contains the unit tests for **Project A**
  - `mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll` -- *Does not* contain `System.Fakes.ShimDateTime`
- ProjectB.Tests/bin/Debug/

  - `ProjectB.Tests.dll` -- Contains the unit tests for **Project B**
  - `mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll` -- Does contain `System.Fakes.ShimDateTime`

---

I'm not sure what the **Visual Studio IDE** is doing differently, but the **vstest.console.exe** seems to load all of the assemblies, ignoring duplicates based on fully qualified names. That is, it loads the following files:

- ProjectA.Tests/bin/Debug/ProjectA.Tests.dll
- ProjectA.Tests/bin/Debug/mcsorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll
- ProjectB.Tests/bin/Debug/ProjectB.Tests.dll

It ignored the file `ProjectB.Tests/bin/Debug/mcsorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll`, which had the type `System.Fakes.ShimDateTime` defined within it.

The only solution to this is to run a separate `vstest.console.exe` per test project (instead of all at once), or to ensure that the generated Microsoft Fakes assemblies (*.Fakes.dll) have the same types defined across the board, so it doesn't matter which version of `mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll` is loaded. And, since the **Azure Pipelines VsTest** task uses a single run of **vstest.console.exe** this is important to know.